# unable to download image from firebase storage using WebClient

Tags: c#, firebase-storage

I have an image file that is saved in firebase storage under the path image/test.png that I am trying to access via a C# script. I can open the image in a browser (chrome) using the full url to the image that includes parameters (access token), however, when i use this URL in my script i get a "400" response code.

URL: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[project].com/o/[path](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%5Bproject%5D.com/o/%5Bpath) to image]?alt=media&token=[token]

The following C# code is using System.Net.WebClient and has been my first few attempts. I'm working inside an interpreter and cannot add/install any additional assemblies/libraries and have limited access to other libraries more than System.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Script_Instance
{
    // Define your input and output parameters
    public string RunScript(string DesignName, string UrlHighres, string UrlEdited, string Folder)
    {
        string resultMessage = "";

        // Create a WebClient instance to download images
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            DownloadImage(DesignName, UrlHighres, Folder, "_imagelines", webClient);

            resultMessage = "Images downloaded and saved to " + Folder;
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            resultMessage = "Error downloading image: " + webEx.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultMessage = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }

        return resultMessage;
    }

    // Custom method to download and save an image
    private void DownloadImage(string name, string url, string destinationFolder, string end, WebClient webClient)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        // Download the image from the URL
        byte[] image_data = webClient.DownloadData(uri);

        // Extract the filename from the URL
        string file_name = name + end + ".png";

        // Create the full path to the destination file
        string destination_file = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file_name);

        // Save the image to the destination folder
        File.WriteAllBytes(destination_file, image_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use HttpClient and not WebClient

Comment: "400" response code means that the URL is missing some required parameters or is not properly formatted as Firebase Storage requires certain parameters to be included in the URL to authenticate and access the image. looke for the  URL that should include valid the alt=media and token parameters.